# Creating a method in a class and using it in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

so im trying to write a simple timer program in ruby. I defined my methods in a "Timer" class but when I call them it gives me a NoMethodError. Any ideas why? Thanks for the help.

```
require "Time"
class Timer

 def start
  $a = Time.now

 end

def stop
Time.now - $a
end

end

puts "Type in 'Start'to to start the timer and then type 'Stop' to stop it"
s = gets.start
st = gets.stop
puts st
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending `start` and `stop` to the return value of `gets`, which is a String, not a Timer.

Also, you should use instance variables rather than globals to hold the timer value. And you'll also need to create a Timer instance (or turn Timer into a module, but use an instance variable even then, not a global).

Comment: Is "$" not making a instance variable? I could have sworn "@" made a global. And how do I create a "Timer instance"? you should also note i'm a complete newbie so if i sound like one its cause i am :)

Comment: @bipolarpants: You have it backwards. `@foo` is an instance variable, `$foo` is a global. And don't worry about being new — everyone is at some time or another.

Comment: oh ok cool, thanks. Now I got it to work but I had to create a method in the String class "class String
  def to_t
    Timer.new
  end" and then add it to "s = gets.to_t.start" like that. is there any way around this?

Comment: and sorry for the terribly written format of that last comment I couldn't seem to hit "enter" without it sending the comment :/

Comment: @bipolarpants: Instead of calling `start` and `stop` on the string, create a Timer and call the methods on that. Just create it in the method where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not initialising a class object. So either you need to have an initialise method or you can reference the class in the methods.

eg

```
class Timer

 def self.start
    $a = Time.now
 end

 def self.stop
    Time.now - $a
 end


end
```